# setOnTouchListener not work on RelativeLayout with extend service

Tags: android, android-layout, android-service, android-relativelayout

i have the following code where i want to get the x and y co-ordinates.

```
public class HeadService extends Service {

    private final static int FOREGROUND_ID = 999;

    private WindowManager windowManager;

    // private HeadLayer mHeadLayer;

    ViewGroup mTopView;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mTopView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.activity_invisible, null);


        RelativeLayout rl;
        rl = (RelativeLayout) mTopView.findViewById(R.id.window);




        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);



        windowManager.addView(rl, params);



        rl.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        initialX = params.x;
                        initialY = params.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(params.x), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        logServiceStarted();

        initHeadLayer();

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = createPendingIntent();
        Notification notification = createNotification(pendingIntent);

        startForeground(FOREGROUND_ID, notification);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        destroyHeadLayer();
        stopForeground(true);

        logServiceEnded();
        if (chatHead != null) windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
    }

    private void initHeadLayer() {
        //   mHeadLayer = new HeadLayer(this);

    }

    private void destroyHeadLayer() {
        //  mHeadLayer.destroy();
        //  mHeadLayer = null;
    }

    private PendingIntent createPendingIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        return PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    }

    private Notification createNotification(PendingIntent intent) {
        return new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.notificationTitle))
                .setContentText(getText(R.string.notificationText))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(intent)
                .build();
    }

    private void logServiceStarted() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void logServiceEnded() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "End", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/window"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#80000000"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now when i touch on the screen then i am not able to get the  x and y co-ordinates.

so how can i get the co-ordinates on touch of relative layout?

Comment: is debugger stopping in onTouch method??

Comment: @VivekMishra no i have put the debug point but its not stopped.

Comment: Read first line from this link carefully http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Services by definition have no user interface and if you're trying to add UI elements from a service you doing it wrong.

Comment: But same thing is working if i will put the button. Button click is working.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it.

I have just replace `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` to `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` and it works.

Thanks